# Django-trunk folder under Python27

Tags: django, powershell

Currently I am trying to work with Django in PowerShell , Windows Vista. According to [this blog](http://www.thebitguru.com/blog/view/244-Running%20django-admin%20in%20PowerShell), I need to 
ad a .ps file to PowerShell with the text:

```
$env:PYTHONPATH=“R:\django\packages\django-trunk”
$env:PATH=$env:PATH + “;D:\Programs\Python25\;R:\django\packages\django-trunk\django\bin”
function django-admin {python (gcm django-admin.py | resolve-path) $args}
```

However, I cannot find the "django-trunk" folder anywhere under my Python27 directory. Am I overlooking or 
misunderstanding something? I am using Python 2.7 with Django 1.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

`django-trunk` is meant to be the path to your django installation. `django-trunk` would be the name of the directory if you were using the development version of Django ([according to the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/?from=olddocs#installing-the-development-version)).

Your Django installation is probably in `...python2.7/site-packages/django/`.

Comment: I know I have django installed but how do I know if it's  the development version? It's been a long time since I installed it.

Comment: If you grabbed the development version from `git` then you have that installed. You more than likely don't have the development version installed, so use the path to your Django installation in `site-packages` instead.